# Using Django's selected_related, but still resulting in additional database hit

Tags: django, django-select-related

I have a `UserProfile` model with a `OneToOneField` to `auth.models.User`.
I also have an `Image` model with a `ForeignKey` to `User`.

In one of my views, I get a bunch of `Image`s like this:

```
Image.objects.select_related('user__userprofile')
```

and later, for each image fetched above I do:

```
userprofile = image.user.get_profile()
```

I was expecting that this would not cause another database hit, but it does. What am I doing wrong?

Please note that I think the `.selecte_related()` is actually doing its job, because I can see a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the SQL that gets executed:

```
SELECT * FROM "myapp_image"
INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("myapp_image"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_userprofile" ON (
    "auth_user"."id" = "myapp_userprofile"."user_id")
ORDER BY "myapp_image"."uploaded" DESC, "myapp_image"."id" DESC
LIMIT 64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `image.user.userprofile` does the trick. Also, `get_profile()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
userprofile = image.user__userprofile
```

Comment: Sigh, image.user__userprofile would have been the code for the template. I'm still sleeping...